# MySQL / PHP Average Column Value with specific Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

I have a surprisingly basic question; I thought the answer was going to be more straightforward regarding Averaging columns.  Here is my table with sample values:

**Table: ratings**

```
id, rating, item_id
```

**Sample data**

```
1, 5, 3
2, 1, 2
3, 2, 3
4, 4, 4 
5, 1, 2
```

What if I want to get the average rating of the item_id's marked "3"

The real answer would be 2.5 since there is a 3 with a1, and another with a 5.

Here is the query I believe:

```
 SELECT avg(rating) as average FROM ratings;
```

How do I specify ONLY the ratings with an item_id of 3?  Do I use WHERE?  GROUP BY? something else?

And the second part of the question:  How do I output this into a single variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to specify a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT AVG(rating) AS average
FROM ratings
WHERE item_id = 3
-- returns 1 row
```

If you want to get averages of entire data grouped by item_id you can use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT item_id, AVG(rating) AS average
FROM ratings
GROUP BY item_id
-- returns as many rows as the number of distinct item_ids
```

Comment: That is great thanks.  Second part of question, how do you output this into a variable?  You wouldnt have to loop through it with a fetch_array I dont believe?

Comment: Yes you need to execute the SQL and fetch the first result. If you're expecting more than one row (the second query for example) then you need to iterate over the remaining results.

Comment: Yes, but I am not fetching a "row" technically, so I can't use mysql_fetch_row - right?  This is simply an average of all rows in a column.  A singular number.  so no Array fetching either, or am I off on this?

Comment: Figured it out; $row=mysql_fetch_array($result); echo $row[0];  Marked your answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

Well... have you tried?

```
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings WHERE item_id = 3;
```

If your `rating` collumn is of an integer type, then you may want to do this instead:

```
SELECT AVG( CAST(rating AS FLOAT) ) FROM ratings WHERE item_id = 3;
```

And if you want to save the result in a variable:

```
SELECT AVG( CAST(rating AS FLOAT) ) INTO @var FROM ratings WHERE item_id = 3;
SELECT @var;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the algorithm I've been using in most of my projects. It doesn't require any complex MySQL statements and functions, and at the same time both the retrieval and update of the average rating value affect just a single row, even if you're dealing with millions of ratings. Everything is based on pure math :)

Check it out, hope it will be useful: [Calculating Average Rating the Right Way using PHP and MySQL](http://www.marinbezhanov.com/web-development/18/calculating-average-rating-the-right-way-using-php-and-mysql/)